# There are multiple duplicate values in PostgreSQL. I just want to get the latest one here. What should I do?

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Question

There are multiple duplicate values in PostgreSQL. I just want to get the latest one here. What should I do?

```
first_join_time  | time  | account | status
-----------------+-------+---------+---------
       1000      |  1000 | a       | die
       1000      |  2000 | a       | live
       1000      |  3000 | a       | die 
       1000      |  1000 | b       | die
       1000      |  2000 | b       | die
       1000      |  3000 | b       | live
```

### My expected result

`time` is the time when the user updates the status. I need to get the latest `status` information based on this field and return it. `first_join_time` is the time when the user joins for the first time. If there is no such field, can you get the time when he joins according to time through SQL?

```
first_join_time  | account | status
-----------------+---------+--------
       1000      | a       | die
       1000      | b       | live
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`

```
   with cte as
    (
    select *, row_number() over(parition by first_join_time, account order by time desc) as rn
    from tablename
    )
    select * from cte where rn=1
```